# How to guess the limit in order to show that the space is complete

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

When trying to prove that a certain metric space is complete, I always have the same problem: how to guess the limit? We have to guess it in order to prove that any Cauchy sequence converges to that limit. I wonder if there is a general way to find such a limit for a Cauchy sequence, or at least a few methods which work in most cases.

If the question seems unclear, please let me know.

Comment: The question is clear, but far too broad, far too general, which makes it equally impossible to answer as an unclear question would be. Can you make your question more specific in some way?

Comment: @LeeMosher The question was precisely if there was a general answer to this! So I guess the answer is no: one has to study each case on its one: there is no "method".